# Writing text data from PCollection to GCS with custom file name

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam, dataflow

In a dataflow job written in Kotlin
using a PubSub subscription as input i receive a Proto object (Event) and map this object to Strings.

My pipeline has type:

```
PCollection<KV<Event, String>>
```

These strings are the lines of a file that must be written in GCS.
The Event Object has a "Id" that must be used to set the filename, and a "name" to set the folder.

Is it possible using FileIO ?

```
pipeline.apply(
   FileIO.writeDynamic<String, String>()
     .to("gs://my-bucket")
     // withNaming?

)
```

My goal is to write the right lines in the right files, based on the information in the Event object

Answer (score 0):

File-names can be customized by providing a `FileNaming` implementation to the [withNaming()](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/b0b7578b343946bad49fb1110111674519590856/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.java#L1096) API.

However this currently does not support mapping input elements directly to final file names. Input elements can be mapped to groups using the [dynamic destinations](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/b0b7578b343946bad49fb1110111674519590856/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.java#L222) API and for each group you can provide a file-naming strategy.

To fully customize naming using input element values you might need to implement a new sink transform.